# Does anyone have an idea on how to make this shape on the container?

Tags: css, frontend, tailwind-css

Should I use border-radius, clip-path or what kind of wizardry is this?
I have to make the container to look like in the photo below:

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use mask:

```css
.box {
  --s: 50px; /* control the curvature (can be percentage) */

  margin: 20px;
  height: 250px;
  background: linear-gradient(45deg, red, blue);
  -webkit-mask:
    radial-gradient(55% var(--s) at top   ,#0000 99%,#000) top,
    radial-gradient(55% var(--s) at bottom,#0000 99%,#000) bottom;
  -webkit-mask-size: 100% 51%;
  -webkit-mask-repeat: no-repeat;
}
```

```html
<div class="box"></div>
```